the simplest non-smooth dg algebra?
I'm considering a problem around smooth dg categories. I think a simplest example might be helpful.
Let R be a DVR, k be its residue field, A is a smooth dg R-algebra means A is a $A\otimes^LA$ perfect complex). (following Kontsevich)
So is k a smooth R-dg algebra? And how to give a proof?

The tensor product $k\otimes_Rk$ is the trivial square zero extension $k\oplus k[1]$

Thanks, I think maybe we can see from the k-vector space dimension that $k$ cannot be such a perfect complex? Note that the Euler characteristic/k of a $k\oplus k[1]$ perfect complex must be even but k clearly cannot satisfy this property. My other question is that if A is a general dg k algebra, what is $A\otimes^L_R A$? @Keerthi Madapusi

Yes that's right. As for the general self-tensor product, it depends on $A$! There's not much you can say in this generality, but one necessary condition for smoothness is that $A$ is flat over $R$, which means that its underlying complex has torsion-free cohomology concentrated in degree $0$.

In this situation, the derived tensor product becomes the usual tensor product, since the higher Tor terms vanish

Wow, thanks! Is there any reference for the proposition that A needs to be flat over R? I haven't seen any reference that says Kontsevich's homological smoothness will induce such a flatness condition. (I'm a beginner in dg algebras)

I'm not sure about a reference, but note that the condition on $A$ is invariant under arbitrary base-change along maps $R\to k$, and flatness can be checked by noting that any such base-change with $k$ an algebraically closed field has cohomology concentrated in degree 0. In this way you reduce to the case where $R$ is itself a field.

Btw these comments are assuming you're working with commutative DG algebras in characteristic zero with no cohomology in positive cohomological degrees.

It is easy to compute that $\mathrm{Ext}_{k \oplus k[1]}^\bullet(k,k)$ is a polynomial algebra. In particular, it is infinite-dimensional, hence $k$ is not a perfect complex.

Thank you for your insightful comment, Prof. Keerthi Madapusi. However, I would like to point out that the standard example I consider is $Perf(X)$ for a smooth projective variety $X$. This category is quasi-equivalent to $D(\mathcal{E})$, where $\mathcal{E}=RHom(E,E)$ and $E$ is a strong generator. Your proposed argument appears to encounter difficulties in this case, since $\mathcal{E}$ is not concentrated in degree 0. (and living in a more noncommutative world)
